# Undo all changes on all open files Sublime 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, undo

anyone knows how to undo all changes done on all open files in Sublime 3?
I changed all `</li>` tags on my xml to `<br />` and `<li>` to • and clicked save all on file menu.. when undoing I need to see each file and click ctrl +z.. it will take too long coz i have too many files opened.. i want to back up first the unedited version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit research and got an answer at sublime forum.

Here's how I did it..

Execute this in the console: `[(v.run_command("undo"), v.run_command("save")) for v in window.views()]`.This will undo all the changes made on all open files then save it.

If you don't want to save it all just `[(v.run_command("undo")) for v in window.views()]`

You can open the console below at the extreme left of the status bar and paste that code then press Enter.

Hope this will help someone.